# CR vs LF perl parsing

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which parses a text file and breaks it up per line into an array.
It works fine when each line are terminated by LF but when they terminate by CR my script is not handling properly.
How can I modify this line to fix this

```
my @allLines = split(/^/, $entireFile);
```

edit:
My file has a mixture of lines with either
ending LF or ending CR it just collapses all lines when its ending in CR

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perl can handle both CRLF and LF line-endings with the built-in `:crlf` [PerlIO](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO) layer:

```
open(my $in, '<:crlf', $filename);
```

will automatically convert CRLF line endings to LF, and leave LF line endings unchanged.  But CR-only files are the odd-man out.  If you know that the file uses CR-only, then you can set [$/](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) to `"\r"` and it will read line-by-line (but it won't change the CR to a LF).

If you have to deal with files of unknown line endings (or even mixed line endings in a single file), you might want to install the [PerlIO::eol](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO::eol) module.  Then you can say:

```
open(my $in, '<:raw:eol(LF)', $filename);
```

and it will automatically convert CR, CRLF, or LF line endings into LF as you read the file.

Another option is to set `$/` to `undef`, which will read the entire file in one slurp.  Then split it on `/\r\n?|\n/`.  But that assumes that the file is small enough to fit in memory.

Comment: Does that support anything that `\R` matches?

Comment: @tchrist, do you mean PerlIO::eol?  It's XS, and I haven't closely examined the code, but I think it handles only CR, LF, and CRLF line endings, but that covers every file I've ever seen.

Answer (score 5):

If you have mixed line endings, you can normalize them by matching a generalized line ending:

```
 use v5.10;

 $entireFile =~ s/\R/\n/g;
```

You can also open a filehandle on a string and read lines just like you would from a file:

```
 open my $fh, '<', \ $entireFile;
 my @lines = <$fh>;
 close $fh;
```

You can even open the string with the [layers that cjm shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534591/cr-vs-lf-perl-parsing/7536079#7536079).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just handle the different line endings when doing the `split`, e.g.:

```
my @allLines = split(/\r\n|\r|\n/, $entireFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically split the input into lines if you read with `<>`, but you need to you need to change `$/` to `\r`.

`$/` is the "input record separator". see `perldoc perlvar` for details.

There is not any way to change what a regular expression considers to be the end-of-line - it's always newline.

Comment: Assuming that the file has Windows line endings, wouldn't you change $/ to \r\n?  I don't have a Windows machine switched on right now, so can't try it.

Comment: @Kenny, On Windows, CRLF is normally converted to LF on read, so the default $/ = "\n" is acceptable, and setting it to \r\n would cause problems. He's likely dealing with a Windows file other than on Windows.