# Why is Perl's chomp affecting the output of my print?

Tags: perl, chomp

It's been a couple months since I've been Perling, but I'm totally stuck on why this is happening...

I'm on OSX, if it matters.

I'm trying to transform lines in a file like

```
08/03/2011 01:00 PDT,1.11
```

into stdout lines like

```
XXX, 20120803, 0100, KWH, 0.2809, A, YYY
```

Since I'm reading a file, I want to `chomp` after each line is read in.  However, when I `chomp`, I find my printing gets all messed up.  When I don't `chomp` the printing is fine (except for the extra newline...).  What's going on here?

```
while(<SOURCE>) {
    chomp;
    my @tokens = split(' |,');     # @tokens now [08/03/2011, 01:00, PDT, 1.11]

    my $converted_date = convertDate($tokens[0]);
    my $converted_time = convertTime($tokens[1]);

print<<EOF;
$XXX, $converted_date, $converted_time, KWH, $tokens[3], A, YYY
EOF
}
```

With the `chomp` call in there, the output is all mixed up:

```
, A, YYY10803, 0100, KWH, 1.11
```

Without the `chomp` call in there, it's at least printing in the right order, but with the extra new line:

```
XXX, 20110803, 0100, KWH, 1.11
, A, YYY
```

Notice that with the `chomp` in there, it's like it overwrites the newline "on top of" the first line.  I've added the `$|=1;` autoflush, but don't know what else to do here.

Thoughts?  And thanks in advance....

Comment: Where do you get the data file from? Is it possible it has odd line ending characters?

Comment: It's the common problem Windows file on Unix again. See earlier discussions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881779/neatest-way-to-remove-linebreaks-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836217/perl-or-something-else-m-problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534591/cr-vs-lf-perl-parsing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lines of your input ends with CR LF. You're removing the LF only. A simple solution is to use the following instead of `chomp`:

```
s/\s+\z//;
```

You could also use the `dos2unix` command line tool to convert the files before passing them to Perl.

Comment: Duh!  Thanks so much.  That was it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have DOS line-endings and are running on a Unix build of Perl.

One solution to this is to use [`PerlIO::eol`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO%3a%3aeol). You may have to install it but there is no need for a `use` line in the program.

Then you can write

```
binmode ':raw:eol(LF)', $filehandle;
```

after which, regardless of the format or source of the file, the lines read will be terminated with the standard `"\n"`.